# How to get the output of intermediate layers in Torch7?

Tags: torch

It seems that when I use nngraph model, it is easy to do so.
If I use only normal conv, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

When you define a model, for example a convnet with `nn.Sequential()` and adding modules to it like

```
net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,3,1,1)
net:add(...) -- add other modules
```

you can access to a module with `net.modules[n]` (`n` is the index of the module, use `print(net)` to see your whole network and its modules). Then each module has to state variables `output` and `gradInput` (gradient of the module with respect to its input), then you can access the output of the nth intermediate layer with

```
net.modules[n].output
```